# How To Run A BackGroundWorker And Also Append A Text To A RichTextBox Control From A Delegate That Get Values From Parent Form In C#

Tags: c#, windows

I have a parent form that send a data table to a child form by Delegate.
the Delegate is executed and i have also gotten the the table on the child side.
i want to append a text into my richtextbox control to announce the user what is going on and then run a backgroundworker. but i get the STAThread Exception. i know some thing about Invoke(Delegate) and about single-Thread but i do not know how can i overcome to this cross-threading. Any help is appreciated.

The codes from Appent To RichTextBox are not execute with debugging (i know it is possible with run of the *.exe file).
//What i am doing and trying:(SetDaTableAndFileNameFn is my received Delegate)

```
 public void SetDaTableAndFileNameFn(System.Data.DataTable DataTable)
    {
        //Test The Parent Has Sent And Child Has Received.
        MessageBox.Show("Ruger Parent...");
        dt.Clear();
        dt = DataTable;
        //Check whether My dt Filled Correctly.
        MessageBox.Show(dt.Rows[2][2].ToString());
        richTxtBxExprtr.AppendText(">>> Creating And Transferring Data To The File...");
        //BGWorker.
        bGWExprtrLod.WorkerReportsProgress = true;
        bGWExprtrLod.RunWorkerAsync();
    }

 private void ExportToTxtIrrigularly(System.Data.DataTable DataTable)
    {
    // Using Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application to export datatable.
    }

  private void xBtnExprt_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        SaveFileDialog svFDialXls = new SaveFileDialog();
        svFDialXls.Filter = "Plain text(*.txt)| *.txt";
        svFDialXls.Title = "Export Data As Text";
        svFDialXls.InitialDirectory = @"Desktop";
        if (svFDialXls.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK && svFDialXls.FileName != null)
        {
            WordFilePath = svFDialXls.FileName.ToString();
   //Fire An EventHandler In The Parent Side To Fill A datatable With A DGV.
            ExportImport ExportTxFile = new ExportImport(allRowsExprt, fRowTEndExprt, fRowTEndValExprt, FTRowExprt,
                FTRowValFExprt, FTRowValTExprt, allFieldsExprt, visFieldExprt, slctdFieldExprt);
            OnExportTxFile(ExportTxFile);
 //Filled datatable Will Send Back from parent side with  theSetDaTableAndFileNameFn 
        }
    }

    private void bGWExprtrLod_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
    {
        this.Invoke(new Action(() =>
        {
            richTxtBxExprtr.AppendText(">>> Start Processing...\n>>> Copying Data Take A Little Time.\n>>> Be Patient...\n>>> Loadind Data...\n-----------------------------------------------\n");
            ExportToTxtIrrigularly(dt);
        }));
    }

 private void bGWExprtrLod_ProgressChanged(object sender, ProgressChangedEventArgs e)
    {
            this.Invoke(new Action(() =>{richTxtBxExprtr.AppendText(">>> Line NO. [" + e.ProgressPercentage.ToString() + "]  Is In Progress...\n");
                richTxtBxExprtr.ScrollToCaret();
            }));
    }

    private void bGWExprtrLod_RunWorkerCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
    {this.Invoke(new Action(() => { richTxtBxExprtr.AppendText(">>> The Process Is Completed Successfuly.\n"); }));
    }
```

the executed mthod in the BGWorker will open a savedialogbox() and then export my datatable to a text format using
  Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application

Comment: Since you have a BackgroundWorker(), use that progress event to update the RichTextBox instead of trying to do it directly...

Comment: Thanks for your comment. If I do this way, i will got a cross_threading again!

Comment: How can i invoke RichTextBox.Appen() from BGWorker_DoWork,BGWorker_ProgressChanged and BGWorker_DoWork and BGWorker_RunWorkerCompleted without cross-Threading?

Comment: i have solved BGWorker_DoWorker with this.Invoke(new Action(() =>, but it does not work for in BGWorker_ProgressChanged, BGWorker_RunWorkerCompleted, is there any way to overcome?

Comment: That DataTable parameter is pretty fishy, good odds that this code already runs on a worker thread.  BackgroundWorker can only properly marshal to the UI thread when you call its RunWorkerAsync() method from the UI thread.  Verify this with the debugger, set a breakpoint on the method and when it hits use Debug > Windows > Threads.  With the expectation that you now discover that you don't need a BGW at all.  Or need to make it smarter by also generating the DataTable.

Answer (score 0):

Not really sure what kind of setup you've got, but it will look something like this:

```
private BackgroundWorker bGWExprtrLod;

private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    bGWExprtrLod = new BackgroundWorker();
    bGWExprtrLod.WorkerReportsProgress = true;
    bGWExprtrLod.ProgressChanged += BGWExprtrLod_ProgressChanged;
    bGWExprtrLod.RunWorkerCompleted += BGWExprtrLod_RunWorkerCompleted;
    bGWExprtrLod.DoWork += BGWExprtrLod_DoWork;
}

public void SetDaTableAndFileNameFn(System.Data.DataTable DataTable)
{
    // ... other code ...
    bGWExprtrLod.RunWorkerAsync();
}

private void BGWExprtrLod_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
{
    bGWExprtrLod.ReportProgress(0, ">>> Creating And Transferring Data To The File...");
    // ... do some work ...
}
private void BGWExprtrLod_ProgressChanged(object sender, ProgressChangedEventArgs e)
{
    string msg = e.UserState.ToString();
    richTxtBxExprtr.AppendText(msg);
}

private void BGWExprtrLod_RunWorkerCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    richTxtBxExprtr.AppendText("Transfer Complete!");
}
```

** EDIT **

Start by moving the call to you export method outside the Invoke() call:

```
private void bGWExprtrLod_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
{
    this.Invoke(new Action(() =>
    {
        richTxtBxExprtr.AppendText(">>> Start Processing...\n>>> Copying Data Take A Little Time.\n>>> Be Patient...\n>>> Loadind Data...\n-----------------------------------------------\n");
    }));
    ExportToTxtIrrigularly(dt);
}
```

Comment: I have added BGW component in my form and i did the same thing (codes), but the error has raise again in the BGWExprtrLod_ProgressChanged eventhandler.

Comment: I have done it with the use of this.Invoke(new Action(() =>, but my application freezes until the end of the export method. i have used from BGWorker to prevent from freezing!!!! Is there any point??? Any Guide???

Comment: It sounds like you're using invoke in DoWork, which is pointless. Post more complete code (edit your post) so we can advise how to fix it.

Comment: Idle Mind thanks for your perusing. Unfortunately, outside of this.Invoke()=> , ExportToTxtIrrigularly(dt); does not execute!!!! probably this is because of BGW_progressChanged(). if i do this way, i will get the response of the BGW_Completed(). Is Any Other Way?????

Comment: I don't know what to tell you.  Your code is hard to follow.  It's unclear to me how any of these methods are actually being called.  Look closely at what you've posted above and tell me how the BackgroundWorker actually gets started?!  It looks like you've got a button handler that starts `OnExportTxFile()`...and then what?  Post your actual code, if you want actual help.

Comment: these are all codes, only there are two simple for(int i) loops in the parent side to fill a datatable with a DGV and a loop to export data from DGV to *.txt file. export btn call an eventhandler on the parent side to export DGV to a datatable then at the end of export, a Delegate function pass the datatable to the child side, then a method for export from the received datatable will be call from a BGW_DoWork(),  and the BGW_Dowork() will be call from the received Delegate function. all codes have been written above except mentioned simple loops.

Comment: Here's what I see.  You have a button called `xBtnExprt`, that when clicked, shows a dialog and then runs `OnExportTxFile()`.  Where is `OnExportTxFile()`?  In the method called `SetDaTableAndFileNameFn()`, the BackgroundWorker is started, but nowhere in your posted code is `SetDaTableAndFileNameFn()` actually called.

Comment: Idle_Mind Thanks for your perusing again. I found the problem. as Progress changed is raised on UI thread and i am calling it from the child form entry point, i faced with cross_threading. if i use from Invoke(), for a long loop, loop will be done successfully but the app will get freeze and also the time of the loop will increase too. so i think there is no way except minimal the numbers of calls. special thanks for your try to help me.